# HWIOAuthoBundle with FOSUserbundle. Render Controller not working

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I try to render a controller in my webSite but an exception is triggered:

HERE MY CODE

```
 render(controller("HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:login"))
```

HERE THE MESSAGE

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Controller "HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:login" for URI "/_fragment" is not callable.") in MYBlogBundle::layout.html.twig at line 39

I do not understand because the route is the good one.

vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/HWI/Bundle/OAuthBundle/Resources/Views/Connect/login.html.twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no loginAction in HWIOAuthBundle's ConnectController. Please use connectAction, it will render vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/HWI/Bundle/OAuthBundle/Resources/Views/Connect/login.html.twig template.

```
render(controller("HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:connect"))
```